# Can lumen be ran in a docker container using sail package?

Tags: php, lumen, laravel-sail

I was wondering if it is possible to use the sail package in running a lumen project in a docker container.

I tried editing the supervisor file that comes by default with the sail package like this

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true
user=root
logfile=/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log
pidfile=/var/run/supervisord.pid

[program:php]
#command=/usr/bin/php -d variables_order=EGPCS /var/www/html/artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=80
command=/usr/bin/php -S localhost:80 -t public
user=sail
environment=LARAVEL_SAIL="1"
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
```

And restarted the container and can see the server is running

```
[Tue May  9 15:00:13 2023] PHP 7.4.33 Development Server (http://localhost:80) started
```

But non of the routes are reachable, not even getting a 404 error either. So it seems like the server isn't running.

How can I fix this or get it to work?

Comment: And what is your problem?

Comment: The problem is that though the server is running, I am unable to reach any of the routes